# Replace CUDA cudaMemcpy2DToArray() with OpenCL clEnqueueCopyBufferRect()

Tags: cuda, opencl, porting

I have been working with CUDA->OpenCL porting for a while now. I have a question whose answer I have not found anywhere yet. Thus, I think this will be an interesting question for the CUDA->OpenCL porters.

Everything has been going smoothly for me expect when "translating" one function. This is the **cudaMemcpy2DToArray()** function. A simple CUDA example using this function would look like this:

```
uint8_t*    srcBuffer;
cudaArray*  dstArray;

size_t      pitch;
size_t      x = 700;
size_t      y = 300;

cudaMallocPitch((void **)&srcBuffer,
                &pitch,                     // pitch = 1024
                x*sizeof(uint8_t),
                y);

struct cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<uint8_t>();

cudaMallocArray(&dstArray,
                &channelDesc,
                x,
                y,
                cudaArrayDefault);

/* Fill srcBuffer with some valuable data via a kernel,
   USING pitch when writing to srcBuffer:

   (uint8_t*)((char*)srcBuffer + Row * pitch) + Column = someuint8Value; */

cudaMemcpy2DToArray(dstArray,
                    0,
                    0,
                    (void *) srcBuffer,
                    pitch,
                    x,
                    y,
                    cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
```

The OpenCL version would start looking like this:

```
cl_mem      srcBuffer;
cl_mem      dstImage;

size_t      pitch;
size_t      x = 700;
size_t      y = 300;
```

OpenCL does not have a **cudaMallocPitch()** function. In order to achieve the same behaviour as **cudaMallocPitch()** one should have to first query the device's preferable alignment-size, then calculate the pitch, and lastly allocate the source buffer with the **clCreateBuffer()** function:

```
uint32_t    alignBits;
uint32_t    alignBytes;

clGetDeviceInfo (deviceID, /* Definition not shown here */
                 CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN,
                 sizeof(uint32_t),
                 &alignBits,                        // alignBits = 4096
                 NULL);

alignBytes = alignBits/8;                           // alignBytes = 512
pitch = (x*sizeof(uint8_t) + alignBytes - 1)/       // pitch = 1024
                             alignBytes*alignBytes;

srcBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, /* Definition not shown here */
                           CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                           y*pitchBytes,
                           NULL,
                           NULL);
```

OpenCL does have a function that behaves as **cudaMallocArray()**. This is **clCreateImage2D()**:

```
cl_image_format channelDesc = {CL_A, CL_UNSIGNED_INT8};

dstImage = clCreateImage2D(context, /* Definition not shown here */
                           CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
                           &channelDesc,
                           x,
                           y,
                           0, NULL, NULL);
```

The following code-block is added for consistency:

```
/* Fill srcBuffer with some valuable data via a kernel,
   USING pitch when writing to srcBuffer:

   (uchar*)((char*)srcBuffer + Row * pitch) + Column = someucharValue; */
```

Now are we in the interesting part. The OpenCL function with the closest behavior of that of **cudaMemcpy2DToArray()** that I first could find was **clEnqueueCopyBufferToImage()**. However, this function did not have any *pitch*-parameter. Without a pitch parameter, it would be impossible to make a correctly buffer->image copy since the number of elements differ.
I figured out that I could make use of the OpenCL function **clEnqueueCopyBufferRect()** in order to first copy the data from *srcBuffer* to another buffer that had the same number of elements as *dstImage*. And then lastly use **clEnqueueCopyBufferToImage()**. This is how it looks:

```
srcBuffer_tmp = clCreateBuffer(context, /* Definition not shown here */
                               CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                               x*y*sizeof(uint8_t),
                               NULL,
                               NULL);

size_t src_origin = {0, 0, 0};
size_t dst_origin = {0, 0, 0};
size_t region     = {x, y, 1};

clEnqueueCopyBufferRect(commandQueue, /* Definition not shown here */
                        srcBuffer,
                        srcBuffer_tmp,
                        src_origin,
                        dst_origin,
                        region,
                        pitch,
                        0,
                        x*sizeof(uint8_t),
                        0,
                        0, NULL, NULL);

clEnqueueCopyBufferToImage(commandQueue,
                           srcBuffer_tmp,
                           dstImage,
                           0,
                           dst_origin,
                           region,
                           0, NULL, NULL);

clReleaseMemObject(srcBuffer_tmp);
```

You will notice that this does NOT give the same behavior. We allocated more memory, the *srcBuffer_tmp* buffer. After experimenting a bit I found out that the above code could simply be replaced by:

```
size_t src_origin = {0, 0, 0};
size_t dst_origin = {0, 0, 0};
size_t region     = {x, y, 1};

clEnqueueCopyBufferRect(commandQueue, /* Definition not shown here */
                        srcBuffer,
                        dstImage,     /* DIRECT TO IMAGE */
                        src_origin,
                        dst_origin,
                        region,
                        pitch,
                        0,
                        x*sizeof(uint8_t),
                        0,
                        0, NULL, NULL);
```

This gave me the save behavior as **cudaMemcpy2DToArray()**. However, the usage of the **clEnqueueCopyBufferRect()** function does indeed look INCORRECT. The non-existence of a *Rect*-copy function for Images is obvious as everything is already handled in 2D.

My question is:

Is it safe to assume that **clEnqueueCopyBufferRect()** will behave as a buffer->image copy-function if the image format descriptor (**cl_image_format**) is initialized with the image channel order **CL_A** and an image channel type equal to the element type used in the source buffer?

Comment: From my point of view, `cudaMemcpy2DToArray` and `clEnqueueCopyBufferRect` are equivalent. The only difference is how you are using them. On CUDA a buffer is an image, so it works for both. But in OpenCL an image is not a buffer, although in some implementations they are equivalent is not safe to use it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your final question: no, it's not. Though in practice it might work in one implementation, it might not in another. So even if your code worked, it is not standard, therefor not portable.

The function you are seeking indeed does not exist, not even in OpenCL 2.0, so there is no straight way of doing it from the host. Both CUDA and OpenCL make a clear distinction of Buffers and Images, as in HW they might follow entirely different paths, cache protocolls, etc. Since the copying function in OpenCL does not exist, and there is no way of reinterpreting Image data as Buffer data, your best shot is implementing the function in a kernel with arbitrary workgroup size. Such a kernel would be quite straightforward to implement (though a lot more work than pulling in a baked function), and it should be fairly fast too.

While the standard refers to buffers and images both as cl_mem, the description of the function clearly states that it operates on buffers (yet it does not state that it should fail on images). (Leaky abstractions? Poor documentation?) So while your solution might work, and it might even work on all platforms, it circumvents the standard. Even if it works today in a platform, it might not work tomorrow after an update to the runtime.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time on reading the question!

I understand and agree with you. Since it was not stated in the specification I decided to take the safe way and created another intermediate buffer. Anyway, the idea of using a kernel as a copy-function did not pop-up in my head until I read your post. Thank you for that!